# nargin vs exist

Tags: matlab

Given a function like:

```
function foo(myParam)
if nargin<1
  myParam = 'default value';
end % if
end % function
```

I've seen people use something like the following in the place of the nargin version

```
if ~exist('myParam', 'var')
  myParam = 'default value';
end %if
```

I'm wondering if there is any preference either way?

The "~exist..." version to me has the advantage that if I change the order of my function parameters then it should still work. However my concern with this approach is that I might inadvertently pick up variables that are defined globally or in the scope of a surrounding function in the case of nested functions.

Any thoughts on the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both should work. But...

Exist tends to be slow, since it must look through your workspace for the variable in question. When you write error checks like this, you don't want them to suck up CPU cycles. The test against nargin is a simple test against a single numeric value.

I'd also generally suggest a more extensive test. Something like

```
if (nargin<1) || isempty(myparam)

  myparam = defaultvalue;

elseif

  ...

end
```

Inside the elseif branch, I'll put a set of additional tests to see if the parameter has the expected size, shape, class of variable, etc. If those tests fail, I'll return a friendly error message that explains what was wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I would go with nargin for two reasons:

1. If you change the order of parameters to your function, fixing up the input checking code is going to be the least of your problems; you're going to have to go update all the call sites to your function as well.
2. nargin is far cheaper. exist, even if scoped to just check for variables, has to scan the whole workspace doing a bunch of string comparisons along the way. the nargin method consists of just a scalar less than operation.

Answer (score 4):

I always validate arguments using `nargchk`, and then go with the `nargin` tests as you had them. As others pointed out, they're cheaper, and I think clearer.

In functions that I expect to be re-used heavily, I always put lots of checks up front, and then structure the code to call the real implementation later.

I also tend to structure optional arguments (when not using `varargin`) like this:

```
function x = myfcn( arg1, opt_arg2 )
if nargin < 2
   arg2 = 'default';
else
   arg2 = opt_arg2;
end
```

as I think this makes it more obvious when editing the file which arguments are expected to be optional.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with the [NARGIN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/nargin.html) option, for the reasons listed by [SCFrench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733646/nargin-vs-exist/733772#733772). One additional benefit: I often find myself using it in conjunction with a [SWITCH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/switch.html) statement when I have more than 2 input arguments:

```
function outArgs = my_fcn(inArg1,inArg2,inArg3)
  switch nargin,
    case 0,  % No input case
      error('Not enough inputs!');
    case 1,  % Set last 2 inputs to default
      inArg2 = 'yes';
      inArg3 = 'on';
    case 2,  % Set last input to default
      inArg3 = 'on';
  end
  ...
  % Checking of variable types and values would go here! 
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3):

**For those using MATLAB R2007b or later, 
here is a better answer: [InputParser](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html)**

It saves the trouble of having to synchronize any addition, removal, renaming and reordering of arguments.

(How much you save would depend on your coding style, but there is not a more neat way than InputParser.)

I have not tested it for speed, but if you function takes more than 1000 milliseconds to run, there's no reason to be concerned by the speed of InputParser.

Example:

```
function AbCdEfGhIj(ffff, ggggg, varargin)
opts = inputParser;
opts.addRequired('ffff', @(p)(ischar(p) && size(p,1)==1 || iscell(p)));
opts.addRequired('ggggg', @(p)(iscell(p) && all(cellfun(@ischar,p))));
opts.addOptional('Recursive', false, @islogical);
opts.addOptional('IncludeFullPath', logical([]), @islogical);
opts.parse(ffff, ggggg, varargin{:});
opts = opts.Results;
if isempty(opts.IncludeFullPath),
    opts.IncludeFullPath = iscell(opts.fffff) || opts.Recursive;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly prefer `exist` over the `nargin` option for two reasons.

**1.** 
After reading a lot of code from people who were never taught to look back at their own code, I have only felt stronger for this, as `exist` makes the code readable.
For example, I encountered once a function like this. For your convenience I gave the variables sensible names:

```
[model, accuracy] = epicModelingFunction (dataMatrix, responseVector, indicatorForCategoricalVariables, optionsForInternalFunctions, typeOfDistanceCalculation, notationForMissingValues, isClassificationAndNotRegression, scalingMethod, shouldPlotAllIntermediateStuff)
% EPICMODELINGFUNCTION is actually a horrible function to read and not epic at all
% ...
```

This was then followed by `if nargin < n` for every variable other than the first two. The only reason I could follow what the `nargin(n)` should be without counting the header input, is that the `if nargin < n` was always followed by (only sometimes a few lines of code and) the declaration of the missing input with the default value. For bigger chucks of code in the `if nargin < n`, I would definitely lose track.

**2.** `exist` doesn't really check the complete workspace *if called from a function*. Sure, comparing two numbers is less expensive as comparing a few strings, but if used at the beginning of a function to fill in default values for the not given parameters, it is fine. Consider the following function:

```
function testExist(C)
if exist('B', 'var')
    disp('''exist'' in a function checks the workspace.')
elseif exist('C', 'var')
    disp('''exist'' in a function ignores the variables in the workspace, but checks the function space.')
else
    disp('''exist'' is broken or no parameter was given.')
end
end
```

And then executing the following:

```
A = magic(3);
B = magic(4);
testExist(A)
```

results in this output:

```
'exist' in a function ignores the variables in the workspace, but checks the function space.
```