# call matlab function without all its arguments

Tags: matlab

```
function y = myFunc(tR,mode)

if ~isfield(tR, 'isAvailable')
    tR.isAvailable= false;
end

if tR.isAvailable
y = fullfile(workingFolder,'file.txt');
else
y = '';

switch(mode)
case '1'
.....    
case '2'
.....
end
end
```

when I call myFunc(tR,'1') it'es OK
but I would also to be able to call myFunc sometimes without the mode just myFunc(tR)

how could I say in some cases within the function myFunc don't execute the switch case when the mode varaible isn't provided in arguments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The use of [exist](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) is probably the neatest and simplest way to do this if you want to exclude elements 'at the end', though [`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) can also do the trick. In general I would use `nargin` if variables have meaningfull positions or no meaningfull names, and `exist` only if they have meaningfull names. [See this question for more about this choice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733646/nargin-vs-exist)
2. The use of [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) is probably the neatest way to do this if you want to exclude elements in general.
3. However, if you just want to exclude 1 element in the middle, a simple alternative would be:

If you don't want to use the `mode`, give it as `[]`, then you put your switch statement inside this:

```
if ~isempty(mode)
    % Your switch statement here
end
```

Of course the risk is that strange things will happen if you forget to use the `if` statement later in the same function.

Comment: `nargin` is as simple to implement as your `NaN` idea but makes much more sense and allows you to call the function with a single argument. I recommend against the `NaN` hack.

Comment: yes but when I call the function myFunc(tR), I got error as if mode is nan ?

Comment: @lola The `NaN` workaround is not a solution to call your function with 1 element, it is just allowing you to call it as: `myFunc(tR,NaN)` and avoid the switch statement. If mode is your last input argument this won't gain much, but if your function is like this: `muFun(a,mode,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)` this will save you the work of dealing with `mode` AND all trailing input arguments.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but can you replace `NaN` with `[]`? That way you could stick with more standard syntax.

Comment: @Dan Nice suggestion, tested it and it works. I guess this is what Mathworks also uses now and then.

Comment: +1 then, this a good solution for the general case. To me `varargin` is only when you can have a wide range of arguments that usually don't get called, so functions like `plot` for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) in your function to provide some defaults inputs when not enough inputs are provided by the user.

Comment: `nargin` is the way to go here. The `varargin` suggestions are overkill if you only have one optional argument. This will be the cleanest and simplest way.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Dennis Jaheruddin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19052301/1292374) gives a good list of possibilities, but I also find using `exist` a useful method:

```
if exist('mode', 'var')
    % Your switch statement here
end
```

Comment: As you already describe my answer as a list, I have been so free to include this one in the list as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use varargin, but you need to access the parameters differently then.
Also, check with nargin how many arguments you've got.

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html

Your function declaration would read:

```
function y = myFunc(tR, varargin)
```