# How to get the number of arguments of the caller function in Matlab2015b?

Tags: matlab

The below code should run successfully. The assert statement passes in **Matlab2014b**, but fails in **Matlab2015b**.

How would you get the number of arguments for the caller function in Matlab2015b?

```
function test()
    fnA(1);
end

function fnA(A1, A2)
    n = nargin;
    fnB(1, 2);
    assert(n==A2, '%d does not equal %d', n, A2);
end

function fnB(B1, B2)
    n = evalin('caller', 'nargin');
    assignin('caller', 'A2', n);
end
```

Comment: Excuse me, but why on earth would you want to do this?:) Anyway, have you tried saving your `nargin` by a new name in `fnA` and testing for that? From [matlab doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html): "*nargin returns the number of input arguments passed in the call to the **currently executing function**. Use this nargin syntax only in the body of a function.*". (emphasis mine)

Comment: Was hoping to find a solution where you would not need to modify fnA to work. The use case is setting the default value for missing parameters in the caller function (fnA).

Comment: Why not check `nargin` manually and set the defaults there? Or after obtaining said valies from `fnB`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I got it wrong. Anyway, I agree with your comment about how it should be done

Comment: `nargin` is definitely the way to go. Functions from the `eval` family tend to break all things MATLAB related, thus going with @AndrasDeak's suggestion is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I agree with @AndrasDeak regarding the `nargin` check. Alternatively, you can have a bunch of `if ~exist('varname','var'), varname = some_default_val; end` - one for every input of your function.

Comment: @Adriaan Even `evalfr`?

Comment: @IKavanagh no idea, never used that. But just based on the name I'd say no :P

Comment: Getting the same unexpected behaviour in R2016a and R2016b. @AndrasDeak - I'm building an exception throwing and handling library and want to be able to do something like `exception.assert_nargin(4);` at the start of a function that is expecting four arguments. This method would use `evalin('caller','nargin');` rather than having to pass in this number each time.

Comment: @b3 yeah, I see why `exception.assert_nargin(nargin,4)` would be cumbersome, but I don't know if there's a way out. Especially for newer versions of MATLAB, which I'm unfamiliar with. I can imagine some OOP magic that could somehow store the `nargin` automatically, but I'm also too unfamiliar with MATLAB OOP to be able to tell if this is possible. Then again, you can check `numel(varargin)` as per the answer below, but then you have to handle non-`varargin` input parameters.

Comment: I heard back from Mathworks on this: "As you have noticed, the behavior of `evalin` using the `caller` workspace with `nargin` (and `nargout` as well) was changed in MATLAB R2015b. From that release onwards, to obtain the `nargin` of a caller function, you must pass `nargin` from the `caller` function directly as an argument."

Answer (score 3):

This is what I managed to do on MATLAB 2015b:

```
evalin('caller','numel(varargin)'); %// If you are/don't mind using varargin @ caller
```

Alternatively, in the caller assign `nargin` to a variable (e.g. `narg = nargin;`), then you can use:

```
evalin('caller','narg'); %// If you assigned the caller's nargin to "narg"
```

---

Other than that, the *more commonly used* methods to check your functions' inputs and set defaults are:

1. Logic based on `nargin`:

   ```
   function test_func1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
     if nargin < 3 %// 2, 1 or 0
       arg3 = default_val_3;
     end
     if nargin < 2 %// 1 or 0
       arg2 = default_val_2;
     end
     if ~nargin %// same as nargin==0
       arg1 = default_val_1;
     end
     ... // rest of your code
   end
   ```
2. Logic based on `exist`-ence of variables:

   ```
   function test_func1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
     if ~exist('arg3','var'), arg3 = default_val_3; end
     if ~exist('arg2','var'), arg2 = default_val_2; end
     if ~exist('arg1','var'), arg1 = default_val_1; end
     ... // rest of your code
   end
   ```
3. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733646/nargin-vs-exist) for more ideas.

---

This is what I used to test different options (save the following code as `test_caller_nargin.m`):

```
function test_caller_nargin(varargin)

print_caller_nargin();

function print_caller_nargin
  evalin('caller','numel(varargin)')
end

end
```